# Want to hide scrollbar when a absolute div already has a 100% height

Tags: html, css, background, html5-video

I am having a client's Html Site Project, Where I used a video in the background of site's homepage, I used a absolute `div` outside of `video` with `100%` `height` and `width`, My Client don't want a scrollbar on y-axis & I also cant use `overflow:hidden;` property of CSS, may be Client will adds some content in future, I am still confused if i have given 100% height and width to parent element of video then from where the scrollbar is coming when I use bottom:0 poperty with that div then scrollbar won't show but the size of video would be changed, why its happening please help me. Thanks in advance & and forgive me if I could not clear the exact problem which I am getting.

Site URL: http://trekoholic.com/site/

I used `body { overflow-y: hidden; }` as a temporary basis

CSS and HTML:

```css
div#video-player {
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="video-player">
  <video width="100%" height="100%" loop="" autoplay="">
    <source type="video/webm" src="Video/eat.webm"></source>
  </video>
</div>
```

Comment: I am not getting any scroll bar on any axis. This seems a cross browser issue that is generated by the way browsers and operating systems render their ui controls. I am on chrome + mac and no scroll bars are shown. My guess is this is a case which you have to explain to your client that default browser behaviors should be embraced, not forced to work they way they weren't meant to. If they add content in the future the site will have scroll bars on all browsers. Hope it helps....

Comment: `body {
  overflow-y: hidden;
} ` please check it on site, sorry to tell about this css previously in question , but this i did only for temporary purpose, please check it again and remove the overflow:hidden from the body while inspect css

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have to change

```
div#video-player {
   position: absolute;
}
```

by

```
div#video-player {
   position: fixed;
}
```

it works but has a counter, if the video has the largest height to the height of the bottom of the screen will not see, but if I understood correctly, this is desired, even in the future will allow you to add more content and will be seen without problems

if you want the full video display just add `height: 100%` to `div#video-player`

```
div#video-player {
   position: fixed;
   height: 100%;
}
```

the counter, if the video has different proportions than the screen may not fill the entire width

so I really hope this helps

Comment: thank you so much! I was having the same problem